# Magento base template legacy doctype

Tags: template, html, validation, bug

The default design templates for magento (i.e 1/2/3-columns) located in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/` all specify the `DOCTYPE` attribute as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

When using validation services, such as:

- http://app.validator.pro/ or
- http://validator.w3.org/

app validator in specific gives the following error message:

> Error: Legacy doctype. Expected e.g. !DOCTYPE html.

As a result there are additional, non-valid errors displayed on the page because the doctype specified is not seen as valid, so it default to HTML 4.01 Transitional.

Changing the template source as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Gets rid of these errors & now the validator services now display fewer & more relevant errors.

- Anybody know why Magento is still doing this, even [in 1.9](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/1column.phtml)?
- Is this detrimental from an SEO perspective?
- Why is the page being declared as XHTML?

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine the switch hasn't been made to using `<!DOCTYPE html>` - being HTML5 purely for backwards compatibility.  If the switch was made you could then use all of the HTML5 elements many of which would not be supported by older browsers.  (X)HTML isn't of course the latest standard, but I wouldn't call it legacy yet, or at least not to the extent that you should start avoiding it.

To answer your other questions, no I don't believe it to be detrimental from a SEO perspective, and who knows why Magento chose XHTML 1.0 strict over HTML 4 but it is in my opinion a better standard requiring better formatted code than HTML 4.